# Display mode-line on multiple lines

Tags: mode-line, mode-line-format

How do I set the mode-line to display using multiple lines, as required (or even statically), to fit in all of its contents?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829780/how-to-make-multi-line-mode-line-in-emacs-23

Comment: The answer is, you don't. The mode-line is a single line of text. Put the information somewhere else.

Comment: In principle something like that should be possible with saving `mode-line-format` in a variable `my-mode-line-format`, setting `mode-line-format` to `nil`, displaying a "modeline-buffer" with content `(format-mode-line my-mode-line-format)` and calling `(fit-window-to-buffer)`. Synchronizing the modeline-buffer with the associated buffer is maybe an headache. But, maybe you only need that occasionally. Then you could bind the display of the full modeline to a key sequence.

Comment: @Drew: fair enough; but I am not the one putting all the mode names into the mode-line.  I am happy with a solution that allows access to this information in a different way.

Comment: @Tobias: do you want to put your comment as an answer?